# Collaborating via Zoom meetings using Latex

Tags: collaboration

I need to find a way to collaborate with a math coach via Zoom where we could use Latex typsetting to pass mathematical text to each other in real time.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se Overleaf allows collaborative editing. But I suspect what you mean by LaTeX is really the kind of web based support that is found e.g. on other sites here. Are you already a LaTeX user?

Comment: I am just learning Latex, but have some proficiency at entering in equations.